# iOS Safari text input cursor appears outside input box

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, mobile-safari

I'm seeing a bizarre issue on iOS (8.4) Safari with a text input on a web page, where the input cursor is showing to the right and outside of my input box, when I apply a font-size, width and padding to style it as I want (and to prevent the auto-zoom on focus).

Screenshot showing issue below:

[image: Cursor showing to right of input box]

I'm applying the following styles in my CSS to the input element (type email):

```
font-size: 16px; width: 96%; padding: 2%;
```

It is in containers that are displayed block, no margin or padding, and widths of 100%.

And I have the viewport tag set as such:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Is this a known bug and is there a workaround? Or is there something in my CSS that is causing this issue?

Comment: Also see this [iOS Safari 8 input overflow scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544163/ios-safari-8-input-overflow-scroll), again very interesting thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339063/ios-11-safari-bootstrap-modal-text-area-outside-of-cursor/47710508#47710508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding `overflow: hidden` to the `<input>` CSS? I don't have a device running iOS 8.4, but that seems like it should do the trick.