# How can I properly position a cursor on IOS11 Safari in popup forms?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, mobile-safari, ios11

After we upgraded my iPhone to IOS11, I started seeing a cursor in a random position in my login window. This also happens on Chrome / IOS11. The position of the cursor is marked red on screenshots below.

[image: Login screen with misplaced cursor]

[image: Another screen with the same problem]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 11 Safari bootstrap modal text area outside of cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339063/ios-11-safari-bootstrap-modal-text-area-outside-of-cursor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding `position: fixed` to the body of the page.

Answer (score 4):

Piggybacking off of ybentz's answer. If you use the bootstrap modal, you can add this to your main.js file:

```
 var savedScrollPosition;

 $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
     savedScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
 });

 $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
     window.scrollTo(0, savedScrollPosition);
 });
```

And then this to your css because you'll already have the modal-open class being added anytime the modal pops:

```
body.modal-open {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks for the help ybentz!! I would've responded to your comment, but I don't have the reputation to do so yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ignacios Answer solved the Problem for me.
If i show an overlayer/modal i add the class fixed to the body.
Also add to css this rule:

```
body.fixed{
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the `position: fixed` solution on the `body` does solve it so that's great. One thing to note though is that adding the class to the `body` causes the browser to "jump" to the top of the page so when you remove it when the popup/modal is closed it might be confusing for the user.

If your popup/modal is full screen on iOS what you can do to fix it is save the scroll position before adding the `position: fixed` class with something like this (using jQuery but can be done easily with [vanilla js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)):

```
var savedScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop()
$('body').addClass('has-fullscreen-modal')
```

and then restore it on popup close like this:

```
$('body').removeClass('has-fullscreen-modal')
window.scrollTo(0, savedScrollPosition)
```

and your css will be

```
body.has-fullscreen-modal {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, `position: fixed` **scroll to top automatically**. Quite annoying !

**To avoid penalizing other devices and versions** I apply this fix only to the appropriate versions of iOS.

---

## **VERSION 1 - All modals fix**

**For the javascript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Detect ios 11_x_x affected  
    // NEED TO BE UPDATED if new versions are affected
    var ua = navigator.userAgent,
    iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(ua),
    iOS11 = /OS 11_0|OS 11_1|OS 11_2/.test(ua);

    // ios 11 bug caret position
    if ( iOS && iOS11 ) {

        // Add CSS class to body
        $("body").addClass("iosBugFixCaret");

    }

});
```

**For the CSS**

```
/* Apply CSS to iOS affected versions only */
body.iosBugFixCaret.modal-open { position: fixed; width: 100%; }
```

---

## **VERSION 2 - Selected modals only**

I modified the function to fire only for selected modals with a class `.inputModal`

Only the modals with inputs should be impacted to avoid the scroll to top.

**For the javascript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Detect ios 11_x_x affected
    // NEED TO BE UPDATED if new versions are affected 
    (function iOS_CaretBug() {

        var ua = navigator.userAgent,
        scrollTopPosition,
        iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(ua),
        iOS11 = /OS 11_0|OS 11_1|OS 11_2/.test(ua);

        // ios 11 bug caret position
        if ( iOS && iOS11 ) {

            $(document.body).on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
                if ( $(e.target).hasClass('inputModal') ) {
                    // Get scroll position before moving top
                    scrollTopPosition = $(document).scrollTop();

                    // Add CSS to body "position: fixed"
                    $("body").addClass("iosBugFixCaret");
                }
            });

            $(document.body).on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                if ( $(e.target).hasClass('inputModal') ) {         
                    // Remove CSS to body "position: fixed"
                    $("body").removeClass("iosBugFixCaret");

                    //Go back to initial position in document
                    $(document).scrollTop(scrollTopPosition);
                }
            });

        }
    })();
});
```

**For the CSS**

```
/* Apply CSS to iOS affected versions only */
body.iosBugFixCaret.modal-open { position: fixed; width: 100%; }
```

**For the HTML**
Add the class **inputModal** to the modal

```
<div class="modal fade inputModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    ...
</div>
```

**Nota bene**
The javascript function is now self-invoking

REF : [iOS 11 Safari bootstrap modal text area outside of cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339063/ios-11-safari-bootstrap-modal-text-area-outside-of-cursor)

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed this issue with this CSS

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    body {
        position:fixed !important;
        overflow:auto !important;
        height:100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this fixed your issue, and how this CSS helped your resolve the problem?

Comment: Its just the `position: fixed` part that has "fixed" the issue.