# Textarea not showing up anything on iOS Safari Mobile

Tags: ios, css, textarea, mobile-safari

I have a textarea element in a form. When I click on a button the form will show up(with dynamic html) and I am able to see the textarea element with all the styles.

But, when I click on the textarea to type, except the cursor every style of that textarea is disappearing. I am not able to inspect this because it is only happening on iOS Safari browser.

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: please do provide with some code.

Comment: I don't have styling that rendered in Safari but somehow the default browser agent applying some styles on it. I have read some posts about but not able to figure out the exact issue which is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Form show up in modal?

Maybe you have same problem with this case.
[iOS 11 Safari bootstrap modal text area outside of cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339063/ios-11-safari-bootstrap-modal-text-area-outside-of-cursor/46367269#46367269)