# Strange behavior of input cursor with mobile keyboard opened

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a web app where I have a login form and when I open this page on iPhone device I found the attached behavior where the cursor is faraway from its input in this always happened when the mobile keyboard is opened.

[check the case in action](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4tqeph4vrcyrgy/video-1508139478.mp4?dl=0)

[link to website](https://optinspin.com/)

Any idea about what the problem or any suggestion will be appreciated.

**update:**
the issue is happens on any web browser on iPhone with iOS 11 **Only**.

Comment: Sounds like you ran into the iOS 11 rendering bug. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339063/ios-11-safari-bootstrap-modal-text-area-outside-of-cursor).

Comment: yes that exactly what happened.