# Cannot move cursor to start if i type long text in IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, safari

In safari browser, if you type long text in any input field and then move your cursor to starting point, You can't. i have seen similar question on [Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19957216) and i know its [safari bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=148061) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544163/ios-safari-8-input-overflow-scroll) and [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16988) but i need temporary solution.

Thanks

```css
input {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="This is long text and you cannot read full text in apple safari browser">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544163/ios-safari-8-input-overflow-scroll